# Counting groups of black pixels in a binary bitmap's row

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to come up with a way to display the number of black pixels in groups (one or more) separated by white pixels in a black and white bitmap. Each time the loop encounters a white pixel it should save the `counter` in a label and reset it. This way if I have a group of 5 black pixels, few white and 3 of black again, I'll have 2 of my labels show 5 and 3 in a row.

```
private void CountInRow(int NumOfRow, Bitmap bmp)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=9;i>0;i--)
    {
        if(bmp.GetPixel(i,NumOfRow)==Color.Black)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            //write the value of couter in a label and go to the next label
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is I cannot come up with a way to jump to the next label so I can write the value of the next group in it. All of the bitmaps will have a 10-pixel width.

Comment: Should labels generate dynamically or have you already added the labels to the the form? Could we use a multi-line textbox instead of labels?

Comment: Labels are already there, I'd prefer to stick with them

Comment: Sounds good - do you have a naming scheme for the labels? Are they just "label1", "label2", etc.?

Comment: They're all named lab(numer of the row)x(number in the row), so in a row they'll be like lab1x1, lab1x2 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to write your value to the label, replace your comment with these lines:

```
var name = "lab" + NumOfRow + "x" + i;
((Label)this.Controls[name]).Text = counter.ToString();
```

This will store the value in the appropriate label.